# Paged listview - Set Active Page

Tags: asp.net, pagination

I have a listview that displays products.  I have a datapager associated with the listview.  I control the visibilty/population of product details by a query string value "prodID".  I need to make sure that the right page is active when the page is loaded.  So if prodID 10 exists on page 2 in the listview, then page 2 will be the active page when navigating to the URL (with prodID in the query string).  prodID is a datakey in the listview.

Answer (score 1):

pgProducts.SetPageProperties(itemIndex, pgProducts.PageSize, false);